# Javascript upload eventlistener requires two clicks to fire

Tags: php, html, upload, phpbb

I am trying this code in phpbb but for some reason on the first click it fires the error eventlistener, but then when I click submit file again it starts to show the upload progress. Why?

overall_header.html :

```
<script>
/* Script written by Adam Khoury @ DevelopPHP.com */ /* Video Tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg */ 
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

function uploadFile(){
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    //alert(file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    formdata.append("file1", file);
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.addEventListener("loadstart", loadStart, false);  
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
ajax.open("POST", "root/file_upload_parser.php"); ajax.send(formdata);
//alert(ajax);
}

function loadStart(event){
_("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText; _("progressBar").value = "fuck";
}


function progressHandler(event){
_("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100; _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent); _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
}

function completeHandler(event){
_("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText; _("progressBar").value = 0;
}

function errorHandler(event){
_("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
}

function abortHandler(event){
_("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
</script>
```

posting_attach_body.html

```
    <div class="inner"><span class="corners-top"><span></span></span>

<p>{L_ADD_ATTACHMENT_EXPLAIN}</p>

<fieldset class="fields2">
<dl>
    <dt><label for="fileupload">{L_FILENAME}:</label></dt>
    <dd>
        <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" maxlength="{FILESIZE}" value="" class="inputbox autowidth" /> 
        <input type="submit" name="add_file" value="{L_ADD_FILE}" class="button2" onclick="uploadFile()" />
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl>
<dt><label for="urlupload">{L_URLUPLOAD}</label></dt>
<dd>
    <input type="url" name="urlupload" id="urlupload" maxlength="{FILESIZE}" value="" class="inputbox autowidth" /> 
    <input type="submit" name="add_file" value="{L_ADD_FILE}" class="button2" onclick="upload = true;" />
</dd>
```

Comment: You should post the generated HTML (the one interpreted by the browser).

Comment: What do you need, the browser page source code? It wont fit here, there is a limit of 30000

Comment: Try `onclick="uploadFile(); return false;"`. I think what happens is that the ajax request is started, but as the form submission is not cancelled it immediately results in error.

Comment: adding return false; definitely makes the progress bar work on the first click which is good. The problem is that it stops the form from actually submitting. The progress bar displays progress to the end of the bar then nothing. I can alse see that instead of a stop button on my browser to force the page to stop it is a reload button instead which means that it has indeed already stopped sending. So I still need a fix for this.

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle please.

Comment: @JizboJonez What are you trying to do? You are submitting form via AJAX **and** want to submit the form **again** with usual request? Explain, please, right now it does not make much sense.

Comment: all I want to do is trigger a html5 upload progress while a file is being submitted the normal way through phpbb. So I want javascript to watch the progress of the upload, not do anything else, just watch the progress and report it.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
<input type="submit" name="add_file" value="{L_ADD_FILE}" class="button2" onclick="uploadFile()" />
```

instead of;

```
<input type="submit" name="add_file" value="{L_ADD_FILE}" class="button2" onclick="upload = true;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that the form is submitted just after the ajax call, stopping the ajax request and firing error event.

Change the onclick event of your form like that :

```
onclick="uploadFile(); return false;"
```

So your form won't be submitted directly.
Then, submit your form when ajax request is over (complete event) :

```
function completeHandler(event){
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText; _("progressBar").value = 0;
    _("my_form_id").submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add some logging statements (see JavaScript console) as follows to see what really happens in your script. You say that the upload works fine and that the HTML is not updated as expected.

I suspect that `event.target.responseText` is wrong. `responseText` is property of `XMLHttpRequest`.

```
<script>
/* Script written by Adam Khoury @ DevelopPHP.com */ /* Video Tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EraNFJiY0Eg */ 
function _(el){
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

function traceMsg(msg) {
    // Comment the function to disable logging; 
    // This works in Google Chrome and Firefox.        
    console.log(msg);
}

function uploadFile(){
    traceMsg("uploadFile(): Start");
    var file = _("file1").files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();
    traceMsg("uploadFile(): " + file.name+" | "+file.size+" | "+file.type);
    formdata.append("file1", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.addEventListener("loadstart", loadStart, false);  
    ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("load", (event) {
         traceMsg("completeHandler(event): Start");
         traceMsg("completeHandler(event): Response text:"); 
         // I SUSPECT THAT THIS LINE IS NOT ALL RIGHT.
         traceMsg(event.target.responseText);  
         // IS THIS CORRECT?
         traceMsg(ajax.responseText); 

         _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText; 
         _("progressBar").value = 0;
         traceMsg("completeHandler(event): End");
    }, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
    ajax.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "root/file_upload_parser.php"); ajax.send(formdata);
   //alert(ajax);
    traceMsg("uploadFile(): End");
}

function loadStart(event){
    traceMsg("loadStart(event): Start");
    _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText; _("progressBar").value = "f*ck";
    traceMsg("loadStart(event): End");
}


function progressHandler(event) {
    traceMsg("progressHandler(event): Start");
    _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded "+event.loaded+" bytes of "+event.total;
    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100; _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent); _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent)+"% uploaded... please wait";
    traceMsg("progressHandler(event): End");
}   

function errorHandler(event){
    traceMsg("errorHandler(event): Start");
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";
    traceMsg("errorHandler(event): End");
}

function abortHandler(event){
    traceMsg("abortHandler(event): Start");
    _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
    traceMsg("abortHandler(event): End");
}
</script>
```